# IntelliJ no Main Manifest Attribute after creating jar artifact

Tags: java, intellij-idea, executable-jar

I am trying to build an jar artefact from [this repository](https://github.com/N0W0RK/BWOrgaTool). I imported apache commons io and org.json as libraries. When extracting the artifact I find a Manifest file which only contains the information of org.json. You can find the jar [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4vsueuf5qa9bfg9/BWOrgaTool.jar?dl=0). The manifest file in my Project is not reflected at all. Any help is appreciated. When I run the jar in console with `java -jar` I get the

> Error: No Main Manifest Attribute in XXX.jar.

Comment: what is the action you are doing to create the error?
are you trying to "run" it in intellij?
are you trying to build it with gradle?
are you trying to run it with jar -jar?

Comment: running with java -jar

Comment: the project provided doesnt compile. at least with `gradle build`. i suspect its because you didn't add dependencies to the build.gradle for you dependencies. let me try adding to the build.gradle and see where it ends up.

Answer (score 0):

From the project you provided on github i made the following changes to make it run with `java -jar`. But first and foremost the project you linked on github does not build with `gradle build` on a fresh pull.

to make this run you need to add `commons io` and `org.json` to you `build.gradle` file. this makes the `build.gradle` file look like:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20190722'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'de.bergwacht.esslingen.Main'
        )
    }
}
```

your project also has alot of unused dependencies that should be removed that were creating gradle warnings.

in `AnweseneheitsTableModel` remove the imports:

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.Bool;
```

in `DienstprotokollInvalidArgumentException` remove the imports:

```
import com.sun.javaws.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException;
```

in `MainForm` remove the imports:

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.Bool;
import com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.algorithm.BooleanEncodingAlgorithm;
```

at this point you can run `./gradlew jar` and this will create a jar for you under `build/libs`

you can run that jar with `java -jar build/libs/BWOrgaTool-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

that command will run it, it will encounter a NPE:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.bergwacht.esslingen.forms.MainForm.<init>(MainForm.java:138)
    at de.bergwacht.esslingen.Main.main(Main.java:42)
```

but thats another problem all together, you can start debugging your program at that point.

Comment: Th issue is that I am trying to build with IntelliJ and haven't removed the gradle settings. There is a known issue with Swing and gradle that prevents swing components from beeing initialized properly. This is the reason for the NPE you are seeing. Any idea how to do that.